# Javascript can not log successful Get request response

Tags: javascript, api, get

I am trying to understand why my Javascript can not successfully interpret and log the response from a successful get request.

```
function getNonProfitItems() {
console.log('Get Non Profit Items');
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", 'http://localhost:9000/v1/AdvancedCharityItems?charityItemId=19790&listingType=FixedPrice', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = displayNonProfitItems();
console.log(request.responseText);
}

function displayNonProfitItems() {
console.log(request.responseText);
console.log('Display Non Profit Items Method')
if(request.status === 200) {
    console.log('Request Succsess');
    console.log(request.responseText);
}
```

I can see the request is successful in my browser as it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You're assigning the *result* of `displayNonProfitItems` as the callback for `onreadystatechange`, since you're calling it when doing the assignment. You need to assign the function itself, so it should be: `request.onreadystatechange = displayNonProfitItems`, without the parentheses. That's, at least, one of your problems.

Comment: @NikKyriakides Thanks for your help!